# Adding the results of a Calculated Field

Tags: mysql

I'm doing some homework for school, which includes designing and building a database, and then answering some questions that require you to create queries.

The second to last question asks me to "Display the Total amount billed for each project" 
This is the design for my database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj7Fo.jpg

what I have so far is:

```
SELECT projName, hourlyCharge * hoursBilled as 'ProjectTotal'
FROM hours INNER JOIN project ON project.projNo = hours.projNo 
INNER JOIN employees ON employees.empNo = hours.empNo
INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.jobClass = employees.jobClass
```

which gives me this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuO2i.jpg

The expected output according the homework is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FCZ7.jpg

I've tried A lot of things, using WHERE, EXISTS, IN etc... I'm sure I'm over thinking it, and it's fairly simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`, to get your expected result:

```
SELECT projName, SUM(hourlyCharge * hoursBilled) as 'ProjectTotal'
FROM hours 
INNER JOIN project ON project.projNo = hours.projNo 
INNER JOIN employees ON employees.empNo = hours.empNo
INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.jobClass = employees.jobClass  
GROUP BY projName
```